# Type conversion from pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was trying to solve longest common subsequence  problem . I am facing problem in integer array to pointer conversion . Last element of my 2D array will be result . Here is my code :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

char firstSequence_X[999999],secondSequence_Y[999999];
int length_M,length_N;


void LCS_LENGTH(char*,char*);

int main(void)
{
    LCS_LENGTH(firstSequence_X,secondSequence_Y);
    return 0;

}

void LCS_LENGTH(char X[],char Y[])
{
    //scan
    cout<<"Enter first sequence : ";
    cin>>X;
    length_M=strlen(X);
    cout<<"Enter second sequence : ";
    cin>>Y;
    length_N=strlen(Y);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"First sequence's length is : "<<length_M<<endl;
    cout<<"Second sequence's length is : "<<length_N<<endl;
    //declare 2 matrix : C for length , B for sign
    int C[length_M+1][length_N+1],B[length_M+1][length_N+1];
    //loop variable
    int i,j;
    //clear all
    for(i=0;i<=length_M;i++)
    {
        C[i][0]=0;
        B[i][0]='n';
    }
    for(j=0;j<=length_N;j++)
    {
        C[0][j]=0;
        B[0][j]='n';
    }
    //dp
    for(i=1;i<=length_M;i++)
    {
    for(j=1;j<=length_N;j++)
    {
        if(X[i]==Y[j])
        {
            C[i][j]=C[i-1,j-1]+1;//diagonal+1
            B[i][j]='d';
        }
        else if(C[i-1][j]>=C[i][j-1])
        {
            C[i][j]=C[i-1,j];//up row copy
            B[i][j]='u';
        }
        else
        {
            C[i][j]=C[i-1,j];//left column copy
            B[i][j]='l';
        }
    }
}
cout<<endl<<"C[i,j] :"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<=length_M;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=length_N;j++)
    {
        cout<<C[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<endl<<"B[i,j] :"<<endl;
for(i=0;i<=length_M;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=length_N;j++)
    {
        cout<<B[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

I have to print B and C array . But this error message is showed : invalid conversion from int* to int . Please correct my mistake . TIA

Comment: *Where* do to get the errors or warnings? Is it the *complete* error/warning output by the compiler? Please edit your question to show some marker in the source to show where you get the errors or warnings, and also to include the complete, verbatim compiler messages.

Comment: yes it is complete error . http://imgur.com/EQ39IcG

Comment: Also, C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) so your code is technically not valid C++. Some compiler have it as an extension, but don't rely on it. And the stack (where things like local variables, including arrays) are stored is limited, having a large array on the stack might exhaust the stack space. I recommend you use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead of old C-style strings and arrays.

Comment: Lastly, remember that for a C-style string the value returned by `strlen()` will give the index to the terminating `'\0'` character. That means your loops all go one step to far.

Comment: thanks , I will follow these suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are doing the following things wrong.

```
C[i][j]=C[i-1,j-1]+1;//diagonal+1
```

i think this should be

```
C[i][j]=C[i-1][j-1]+1;//diagonal+1
```

and

```
 C[i][j]=C[i-1,j];//up row copy
```

should be

```
 C[i][j]=C[i-1][j];//up row copy
```

and

```
 C[i][j]=C[i-1,j];//left column copy
```

should be

```
 C[i][j]=C[i-1][j];//left column copy
```